# Common EmberJS Route Events

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there a way to have common events shared among multiple routes in Ember?

Sample:

```
App.CommonMenu = Ember.Mixin.create({
  events: {
    onDelete: function() {}
  }
});

App.MainMenu = Ember.Route.extend(App.CommonMenu, {
  events: {
    onSave: function() {}
  }
});


App.StoreMenu = Ember.Route.extend(App.CommonMenu, {
  events: {
    onSave: function(){}
  }
})
```

I'm only asking because I continue to get an error where, when a button is clicked, I get something similar to this:

```
Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'onDelete'.
```

Comment: Can you share the template where you trigger the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way I can think of handling events globally across routes would be to define them in the `events` hash in your `ApplicationRoute`

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    myEvent: function() {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
});

App.MainMenu = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    onSave: function() {}
  }
});

App.StoreMenu = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    onSave: function(){}
  }
});
```

You could have also some route that handle the same event defined in your `ApplicationRoute` e.g. `myEvent` as long as you return `true` from that handler it will additionally bubble up all the way to the `ApplicationRoute` `myEvent` handler.

```
App.SomeOtherRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    myEvent: function(){
      // do stuff
      return true; // this will make the event bubble up all the way to the ApplicationRoute
    }
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.